# Mysql database not migrating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I created a project in RubyMine and created the database using `rake db:create`, then I tried doing `rake db:migrate` but nothing happened. The terminal just went on the next line.

Under my db folder, are `schema.rb` and `seeds.rb`.

This is what's in my database.yml ([link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkafJ.png))

This is what shows up when I run the server and go to localhost:3000 ([link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkKOL.png))

Comment: did you create any migrations?

Comment: Have you created any models or migrations?

Comment: I'm currently following the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html tutorial, and this happened at section 5, when I changed the routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

```
rake db:create
```

what do you mean by this?  i didn't find this command there.

the 2 simple ways to have a database is to "set it" and then to "create it"

by setting i mean with

```
rails g scaffold Name text:type text:type
```

or

```
rails g model Name text:type text:type
```

after that you need to "create it"

running

```
rake db:migrate # on Rails 4
```

or

```
rails db:migrate # on Rails 5
```

About the RubyMine shortcuts i don't know, because i use sublime+terminal. But u can still use the terminal that RubyMine gives you